# Showing the found keyword in Excel, rather than 'TRUE'

Tags: excel

I'm running a keyword search against a very long list of continuous text that I've concatenated (C2 for the purposes of this example) which works using the following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT( -- ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Keywords,C2))) > 0
```

What I would like to do is add a substitution to show the specific keyword found (rather than TRUE / FALSE) but I don't seem to have much success in setting this up.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: will there be more than one keyword at a time and if so how would you like that to show?

Comment: Yes, it's possible that more than one keyword will be found. Ideally, they should show in the same cell but I could deal with them displaying serially in different cells in the row

Comment: Then your answer is below, TEXTJOIN is available with Office 365 Excel.

Answer (score 1):

If column **E** has the keywords, then try the **array formula**:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($E$1:$E$100,C2)),$E$1:$E$100,""))
```

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar.

Comment: Thank you - this has solved my issue! Much appreciated!!

Comment: @Medusa79 you show your thanks by clicking the check mark by the answer which indicates that this is the correct answer.